# Wi-Fi repeatedly enabled/disabled by radio killswitch

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 20.10

Basically what it says in the title. After some time of being connected to WiFi, my WiFi will start disconnecting and reconnecting about every 5 seconds. rfkill shows that the WiFi interface is blocked at the hardware level when the WiFi is disconnected. /var/log/syslog shows NetworkManager saying that "Wi-Fi is now disabled by the radio killswitch" and then "Wi-Fi is now enabled by the radio killswitch" over and over. My digging into this suggests that this *should* be related to an actual physical button on my laptop to disable WiFi. But it seems like something is going haywire and triggering this button to fire constantly.

I can't find anything online about this specific issue... just people that can't connect because their WiFi is always disabled or something.

Has anybody run into this? Any suggestions on how I might diagnose further? Is there a possible workaround? I never use the WiFi killswitch on my laptop (if it even has one?) so I'd be OK just disabling the killswitch functionality entirely. Can I just safely stop the rfkill service?

This is Ubuntu 20.10 on a System76 Lemur Pro (intel WiFi). I've installed all available updates. Issue happens on multiple networks (home, work, etc.) so computer seems to be the culprit.

Comment: I believe that F11, the key with the airplane on it, is the kill switch. Airplane Mode equals rfkill. I wonder if the button is failing.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea... but that would certainly explain the symptoms.

Comment: try switch off "connectivity checking" in gnome settings app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, this ended up being a hardware issue with the WiFi chipset. System76 sent me a replacement, with installation instructions. I popped it in and I've had no issues since.